# How to find the dates which are there in a week or month till date

Tags: ruby

How to find the dates which are there in a week or month till date.

```
days_for_week should return 19,20,21 (assuming current date is 21st)
days_for_month should return 1..21 (assuming current date is 21st)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Active support provides a lot of useful methods like [at_beginning_of_week](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-beginning_of_week), [at_end_of_week](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html#method-i-end_of_week), at_beginning_of_month etc ..

```
> Date.today.at_beginning_of_week
=> Mon, 20 May 2013
```

For this particular case, you could do

```
> (Date.today.at_beginning_of_week..Date.today).map &:day
=> [20, 21]
```

Similarly

```
> (Date.today.at_beginning_of_month..Date.today).map &:day
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21]
```

or simply

```
> 1..Date.today.day
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first, you could use `Time.now.wday` to get the current week day, then minus that will give you the date of beginning of this week.

For the second, it's much simpler, every month begin with `1st`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I'm reading your question correctly...

The second is simple:

```
def days_for_month
  1..Date.today.day
end
```

The first requires a little algorithm to work back to Saturday:

```
def days_for_week
  days = []
  day = Date.today
  until day.saturday?
    days.unshift(day.day)
    day -= 1
  end
  days
end
```